# Multiple LeftJoin in Doctrine to filter query results

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have some entities with many to one relations

User <--> Department <--> Office <--> Organisation

Also I have another entity called Booking, which is related to User

I need to make a query to only get those Bookings related to a specific Organisation

```
$rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
$queryBuilder
    ->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.user', $rootAlias), 'u')
    ->leftJoin('u.department', 'd')
    ->leftJoin('d.office', 'o')
    ->andWhere('o.organisation = :organisation')
    ->setParameter('organisation', $organisation);
```

this does not work. How can I properly use leftJoin in QueryBuilder when multiple tables are involved?

Answer (score 0):

fix your `php.ini`

`memory_limit=-1`

Comment: I don't think this is a solution. It is using too much memory because there's something wrong

Comment: @user3174311 
what is your `memory_limit` now?